# Displaying shortcode output through Options Framework

Tags: shortcode, options, framework

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me.

I'm using the [Options Framework Plugin](https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-plugin) to customise my site, but I'm having difficulty with using a shortcode in one of the custom fields.

I've created an 'editor' field, and called it in my theme like so:

```
<?php 
  if ( of_get_option('footer_contact_form') ) {
    echo of_get_option('footer_contact_form');
  }
?>
```

But it outputs the shortcode (gravity forms) as raw text, like so: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4676147/shortcode-output.png

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying, or will I have to hard code the form into the theme?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the WordPress function [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).

You can use it to generate the shortcodes, in a string variable, like this :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>
```

So in your case, please try:

```
<?php 
  if ( of_get_option('footer_contact_form') ) {
      echo do_shortcode( of_get_option('footer_contact_form') ); 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Genius!! Really apreciate..